# How to group checkboxes for validation in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, validation, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I have a simple `form` which has 2 `checkboxes`. I want to submit the form if any one of the checkbox is checked. Below code requires to check both of them. I tried grouping checkboxes by using `name` attribute but thats not sufficient, I am missing something. How can we group checkboxes for validation so that if any one is selected then form should be submited. Any suggestion would be helpful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>

    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="Check1" name="select" required>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="Check1">Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="Check2" name="select" required>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="Check2">Option 2</label>
    </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>

<script>

(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');

    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

remove the 'required' from the input tag.

```
<div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="Check1" name="select" >
      <label class="form-check-label" for="Check1">Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="Check2" name="select" >
      <label class="form-check-label" for="Check2">Option 2</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried it earlier. With this form will be submitted without checking any `checkbox`

Answer (score 5):

Try the below.

Essentially it dynamically enables or disables the `required` attribute depending on whether at least one checkbox is checked. Then the browser validation is run as normal. But by only including one `invalid-feedback` div you only see one warning per "checkbox group".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>

    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="Check1" name="select" required>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="Check1">Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="Check2" name="select" required>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="Check2">Option 2</label>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Choose at least one.</div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>

<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    (function () {
        'use strict';
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
            var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
            // Loop over them and prevent submission
            var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
                form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {

                    var failed = false;

                    if ($("[name='select']:checked").length == 0) {
                        $("[name='select']").attr('required', true);
                        failed = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        $("[name='select']").attr('required', false);
                    }

                    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                        failed = true;
                    }

                    if (failed == true) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }

                    form.classList.add('was-validated');
                }, false);
            });
        }, false);
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```